# Find dirrectories paths from a list of names via tramp session

Tags: tramp, find-file

I have a remote host accessing via `tramp` there is a list of directori names I'd like to find on that host.

What I do now - connect to remote server and

`while read -r name; do find / -type d -name "$name"; done < dir_names | tee dir_paths`

Comment: Here is an example where the port is `2222` and the shell/eshell function can be `(shell)` or `(eshell)`; e.g., replace `<call your shell/eshell functions>` with one of the previous functions:  `(let ((default-directory "/ssh:username@ip-address#2222:")) <call your shell/eshell functions>)`.  That will open up a shell of your choice within Emacs and you can run command-line stuff from there.

Comment: Building on @lawlist ‘s answer, you can set the ‘default-directory’ as he indicates, then ‘(shell-command (format (“while read ... -name %s; done” (list-of-names)))’  Now you just need to implement ‘(list-of-names)’ that reads a file dir_names and produces a list of names in the format the shell expects.